# Search a document in Elasticsearch by a list of Wildcarded statements on a single field

Tags: url, search, filter, elasticsearch, wildcard

If I have documents in ElasticSearch that have a field called url and the contents of the url field are strings like "http://www.foo.com" or "http://www.bar.com/some/url/segment/the-page.html", is it possible to search for documents matching a list of wildcarded url fragments e.g., ["http://www.foo.*", "http://www.bar.com/*/segment/*.html", "*://*bar.com/**"]?

If it is possible, what is the best approach to do this?  I have explored [wildcard query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) which only seems to support 1 fragment not multiple.  Filters don't seem to support wildcarding as I have tried using * in a term filter without any luck.

To make it a little more complex, I'm also interested in being able to search by a lot of these fragments.  I have come across [terms filter lookup](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/terms-filter-lookup/) which seems like it is a good solution for dealing with many search terms, but I'm not sure wildcarding works with filters.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You can always use "bool" with a "should" section to combine various other queries or filters.